# Are there any limitations to PHPSpreadsheet Query length?

Tags: mysql, timeout, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I have created a few phpspreadsheet "report" files and all these run fine. I have created my third one, and have now run into a problem where the script doesn't finish running, and now I'm wondering if there is a limitation with regards to how PHP spreadsheet reads nested queries.

I first off created the script from scratch, as with all the others, and then left it over night to run, but the script timed out after an extended time as with the PHP / Mysql Settings I have in place.

Next, I tried running one of my existing scripts, and it worked perfectly, as it had previously.

Lastly, I copied a script from one of the other reports into the current script and to test that there wasn't a template error, and this too run as expected.

I also ran just the query in MySQL workbench, and the query returns results within less than 10 seconds.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c754eb/1

I have added the query I have and removed nested tables just to give a view of the query itself.

```
SELECT 
    CALLING.StoreCode       AS  'STORE CODE'
,   CALLING.RouteCode           AS  'ROUTE CODE'
,   CALLING.ScheduledActionDate AS  'SCHEDULED ACTION DATE'
,   CALLING.ActualVisitedDate   AS  'ACTUAL VISIT DATE'
,   CALLING.CycleEndDate        AS  'CYCLE END DATE'
,   CALLING.CallingDay      AS  'CALLING DAY'
,   CASE 
        WHEN OUTEXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 0
        WHEN EXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE 1
    END             AS  'OUTLET CALLING STATUS' 
,   CALLING.UserName        AS  'USERNAME'
,   CALLING.Week            AS  'WEEK'
,   CASE 
    WHEN OUTEXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate IS NOT NULL THEN OUTEXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate
    WHEN EXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate IS NOT NULL THEN EXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate 
        ELSE NULL
    END             AS  'EXCLUSION DATE'

,   CASE 
    WHEN OUTEXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate IS NOT NULL THEN OUTEXCLUSIONS.LeaveDescription
    WHEN EXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate IS NOT NULL THEN EXCLUSIONS.LeaveDescription 
        ELSE NULL
    END             AS  'EXCLUSION DESCRIPTION'

FROM 

(SELECT 
    CALLCYCLES.StoreCode
,   CALLCYCLES.ScheduledActionDate
,   VISTED.ActualVisitedDate
,   CALLCYCLES.CycleEndDate
,   CALLCYCLES.CallingDay
,   VISTED.UserName
,   CALLCYCLES.RouteCode
,   CALLCYCLES.Week
,   CALLCYCLES.Requestable
FROM
    (
    NESTED QUERY JOINIG TO ANOTHER NESTED QUERY TO REPLICATE AN FULL JOIN IN MYSQL
    )   AS CALLCYCLES
LEFT JOIN
    (
    NESTED QUERY JOINIG TO ANOTHER NESTED QUERY TO REPLICATE AN FULL JOIN IN MYSQL
    )   VISTED
ON
    CALLCYCLES.StoreCode = VISTED.StoreCode
AND CALLCYCLES.CycleEndDate = VISTED.CycleEndDate

UNION ALL (UNIONING THE TWO NESTED QUERIES)

SELECT
    CALLCYCLES.StoreCode
,   CALLCYCLES.ScheduledActionDate
,   VISTED.ActualVisitedDate
,   CALLCYCLES.CycleEndDate
,   CALLCYCLES.CallingDay
,   VISTED.UserName
,   CALLCYCLES.RouteCode
,   CALLCYCLES.Week
,   CALLCYCLES.Requestable
FROM
    (
    NESTED QUERY JOINIG TO ANOTHER NESTED QUERY TO REPLICATE AN FULL JOIN IN MYSQL
    )   AS CALLCYCLES
RIGHT JOIN
    (
    NESTED QUERY JOINIG TO ANOTHER NESTED QUERY TO REPLICATE AN FULL JOIN IN MYSQL
    )   AS VISTED
ON
    CALLCYCLES.StoreCode = VISTED.StoreCode
AND CALLCYCLES.CycleEndDate = VISTED.CycleEndDate
WHERE CALLCYCLES.StoreCode IS NULL

)       AS CALLING

LEFT JOIN

    (JOINING TO REFERENCE TABLE 1)      AS EXCLUSIONS
ON
    CALLING.RouteCode = EXCLUSIONS.RouteCode
AND CALLING.ScheduledActionDate = EXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate


LEFT JOIN

    (JOINING TO REFERENCE TABLE 2)      AS OUTEXCLUSIONS
ON
    CALLING.RouteCode = OUTEXCLUSIONS.RouteCode
AND CALLING.ScheduledActionDate = OUTEXCLUSIONS.ExcludedDate
AND CALLING.StoreCode = OUTEXCLUSIONS.StoreCode
```

Unfortunately there is not error code, except for the timeout and that the script continues to run until it times out.

Comment: It is quite a painful query to wade through. I'd be tempted to start from scratch (or at least something a bit simpler) and see if we can get that working. To that end, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry agree it is quite a painful query.  But sadly, with the data setup, there is not other way of obtaining a result without all the nested joins.  THanks, I'm going to read the link you added now.

Comment: Well, since you've established that the query works in MySQL, perhaps construct a VIEW from this and SELECT from that instead.

Comment: @Strawberry I did try the VIEW option as well.  And then just did a straight SELECT from the view.  I'm busy trying to build the SQL Fiddle but I'm limited to 8000 characters I see.  I want to give enough sample data to get the result from the query.  So just working through the data to give a best result.

Comment: Added a link to sqlfiddle.  Hope I have done this correct.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with PHPSpreadSheet or XLS. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Dave MySQL 8.0